# JQuery .click doesn't work with php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website which connects to a database and displays some pictures. I want to make it so that when you click one of the pictures, it will display an alert but that doesn't seem to work when the images are dynamically rendered. Whenever i try it on jsbin it works but when i try it with a php file it doesn't. I am using jquery and bootstrap.

JSbin: http://jsbin.com/xamovudiroqe/2/

PHP code

```
while($i > $y){

    $picture_query =  mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM images WHERE team = '$full_table_array[$y]' AND teamphoto = 1");
    $picture_array = mysqli_fetch_array($picture_query);

    echo "
        <div data-team=\" ".$picture_array['team']." \" class=\"col-xs-6 col-md-3\">
            <a href=\"#\"  class=\"team-nail thumbnail\">
              <img src=\" ".$picture_array['name']." \" >
            </a>
        </div> 

        ";

    $y++;
}
```

Javascript code

```
   $(".team-nail").click(function() {
    var team = $(this).attr('data-team');
    alert(team);
    alert("hi");
    console.log(team);
});
```

Comment: don't use alerts. `alert()` will block the entire page thread, so nothing will happen while it's showing. Use a javascript based modal dialog library if you really need "dialog boxes" a la alert()

Comment: where is your javascript code on HTML response?

Comment: Also make sure your Javascript is either after the HTML (filled by PHP) or in a document on ready block.  Otherwise the classes won't exist yet when the javascript is trying to assign the .click event.

Comment: `var team = $(this).parent().attr('data-team');`

Comment: you could delegate the bind using `$(document).on('click','.team-nail', function() {`. Also, your `data-team` is on the parent `div`, not the `a`, so it should be `var team = $(this).parent().attr('data-team');`

Comment: Where is the attribute `data-team` in your jsbin example? That's where your alert text is coming from and it appears to be undefined.

Answer (score 1):

I see the problem. You are adding the click event to the anchor element, but the data-team attribute is on the div element. All you need to do is move the data-team attribute the anchor and it will work like a charm.

```
 echo "<div data-team=\" ".$picture_array['team']." \" class=\"col-xs-6 col-md-3\">
            <a href=\"#\"  class=\"team-nail thumbnail\">
              <img src=\" ".$picture_array['name']." \" >
            </a>
        </div>";
```

To:

```
 echo "<div class=\"col-xs-6 col-md-3\">
            <a href=\"#\" data-team=\" ".$picture_array['team']." \" class=\"team-nail thumbnail\">
              <img src=\" ".$picture_array['name']." \" >
            </a>
        </div>";
```